# Use 1 and 0 Instead of True and False in JSON

Tags: php, json, casting, boolean, type-conversion

In PHP, I noticed that if I have an array and then `json_encode()` it, the boolean values get converted to `true` and `false`. However, I want them to be converted to `1` and `0`, respectively.

Here's an example:

```
$data = Array("foo" => true, "bar" => false, "baz" => false, "biz" => true);
print json_encode($data);
```

The above outputs:

```
{"foo":true,"bar":false,"baz":false,"biz":true}
```

However, if `true` and `false` were `1` and `0` instead, we could have a shorter string, which would take less time to transfer over the Internet:

```
{"foo":1,"bar":0,"baz":0,"biz":1}
```

How can I make PHP encode JSON using `1` and `0` instead of `true` and `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. You can use the `array_walk` or `array_walk_recursive` function in PHP to cast the booleans to integers before encoding the JSON. I wrote a function to do that:

```
function change_booleans_to_numbers(Array $data){
    // Note the order of arguments and the & in front of $value 
    function converter(&$value, $key){
        if(is_bool($value)){
            $value = ($value ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }
    array_walk_recursive($data, 'converter');
    return $data;
}
```

Here's a demonstration script:

```
<?php
// Make the browser display this as plain text instead of HTML 
header("Content-Type:text/plain");

function change_booleans_to_numbers(Array $data){
    function converter(&$value, $key){
        if(is_bool($value)){
            $value = ($value ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }
    array_walk_recursive($data, 'converter');
    return $data;
}

$data = Array("foo" => true, "bar" => false, "baz" => false, "biz" => true);

print "Original:" . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($data);
print json_encode($data) . PHP_EOL;
print PHP_EOL;

$changed = change_booleans_to_numbers($data);
print "Processed:" . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($changed);
print json_encode($changed) . PHP_EOL;
```

The script outputs:

```
Original:
array(4) {
  ["foo"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["bar"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["baz"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["biz"]=>
  bool(true)
}
{"foo":true,"bar":false,"baz":false,"biz":true}

Processed:
array(4) {
  ["foo"]=>
  int(1)
  ["bar"]=>
  int(0)
  ["baz"]=>
  int(0)
  ["biz"]=>
  int(1)
}
{"foo":1,"bar":0,"baz":0,"biz":1}
```

Comment: I strongly encourage you to use "true" and "false" (*NOT* "1" or "0") whenever possible in your JSON messages.  Doing otherwise is just poor form.  IMHO...

Comment: I'm more concerned about how long it's going to take to download the JSON.

Comment: If you're seriously trying to save 3 bytes by using 1/0 instead of true/false there's a  99.9999% chance you're prematurely optimizing. And if you aren't, you're engaging in dubious micro-optimization. There are so many more important things like database and filesystem access that have so much more impact on performance. You should listen to @paulsm4.

Comment: I'm really struggling to figure out why you think that the GZIP compression offered by your post-1992 web server won't handle the extra few bytes added by "true" instead of 1. You're misrepresenting the type of the value by representing the bool as an int.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot that my web server has GZIP enabled.